# How to run and keep external codegen in sync in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am planning on having a rust backend and angular frontend for my next project.

I have an external tool that will generate typescript bindings (interface, types, glue code and whatnot) from the rust code by invoking an external tool (ts-rs) that spits out a bunch of TS and .d files.

However I am unsure how to set up angular-cli in order to:

- call the codegen when building the project and include the generated bindings in the project.
- set up the watcher so that in case the rust project changes it will invoke the codegen (and IF the generated code changes, rebuild the project)
- if the angular project changes it will recompile without regenerating the bindings.

A workaround would be to have an external terminal run a watcher external codegen directly, generating the code into the angular project which is picked up by the angular watcher, but it's too error prone (likely to forget to run the external tool).